# Use external font for inline CSS in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Hello there everybody,

I am trying to make a to-do list in react, and in there, I want to change the font to something external, like Montserrat or Roboto. Unfortunately, I am using CSS in an inline way. I am not sure how to add the external CSS. Usually, I copy and paste an @import snippet, which looks like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

Here is my code for my TodoItem(The file for the individual todo item)

```
import React from 'react'

function TodoItem(){
    const styleSpan = {
        fontSize:50,
        fontFamily:"Roboto",
        borderRadius:10
    }
    const styleCheckbox = {
        width:50,
        height:50,
        marginRight:50,
        backgroundColor:"#edc2d6",

    }
    return(
        <div>

            <input type = "checkbox" style = {styleCheckbox}></input>
            <span style={styleSpan}>Todo item here</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

to use inline CSS, you must put your style options in an object. This can work when you have two correlating values, but almost impossible for single values.

How can I add an external font when coding for inline CSS?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add an external font when coding for inline CSS?

You can try something like this -

```
<div>
  <style
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'AdamGorry-Lights';
            src: url(url-to-font) format('woff2');
            font-weight: 300;
            font-style: normal;
        }
      `,
    }}
  />
  <input type="checkbox" style={styleCheckbox}></input>
  <span style={styleSpan}>Todo item here</span>
</div>
```

This allows you to use it in styles as

```
const styleSpan = {
   fontSize: 50,
   fontFamily: 'AdamGorry-Lights',
   borderRadius: 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the css in the parent css file & change the font family.

Have created a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e5h61b?file=style.css). In this demo I have imported the css in the style.css file and have changed the `font-family` to `Roboto`

Comment: thank you brk, but it is possible using the code that I have